# Passar valores para arquivo PHP com JSON

Tags: php, json

Tenho o código abaixo que roda em um PC qualquer e solicita informações para uma arquivo PHP em um servidor remoto.

Como faço para passar um parametro para este PHP utilizando este meu código JSON?

Assim consigo enviar um dado e ter um retorno processado.

Sei que parece algo simples, mas só consegui rodar neste cenário (HTML em qualquer lugar) e PHP (servidor remoto) com este código. Todos os outros métodos precisa ter todos os arquivos no servidor.

Arquivo HTML + JS (Roda em qualquer computador que roda)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var urlTeste = 'http://www.meuservidor.com/servidor.php?jsoncallback=?';
$(document).ready(function() {
//Mensagem enquanto não carrega a pagina
$('#resultado').html('Carregando...');

$.getJSON(urlTeste,null, function(data){
$('#resultado').html(data);   
});
}); 
</script>
```

Arquivo PHP (no servidor www.meuservidor.com/servidor.php)

```
<?php
$var = date("d/m/Y H:i:s "); 
echo $_GET["jsoncallback"] . '(' . json_encode($var) . ');';    
?>
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Ali onde você está passando `null`, passe um objeto:

```
$.getJSON(urlTeste, {chave: "valor", outro: "outro valor"}, function(data){
   $('#resultado').html(data);   
});
```

E no PHP:

```
<?php
$chave = $_GET['chave'];
$outro = $_GET['outro'];
```

Comment: E obrigado por ter seguido minha recomendação na outra pergunta :)

Comment: Resumindo, a chamada basicamente tem que ficar assim: $.getJSON("url.php", {chave: "valor", outro: "outro valor"}, function(data){  $('#resultado').html(data);  
}); o código postado pelo @bfavaretto está corretíssimo, sempre uso a chamada desta forma em meus projetos. Abs

Comment: Realmente funcionou corretamente. Show! Muito obrigado pela ajuda.