# PHP não reconhece codigo Json

Tags: php, json

Instalei o php + apache via Xampp. O PHP está funcionando, mas não reconhece o Json, alguém sabe se precisa habilitar alguma coisa no php.ini?

Retorna o erro: 
Notice: Undefined index: jsoncallback

A linha de retorno é:

```
echo $_GET["jsoncallback"] . '(' . json_encode("Valor=" . $teste ) . ');';
```

O código funciona, já rodei o mesmo código no localhost de outro computador, e também em um servidor remoto, e funciona perfeitamente, apenas neste computador que instalei via Xampp não funciona.

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

O erro que estás a obter:

> Notice: Undefined index: jsoncallback

Indica que o *index* na matriz `$_GET` com o nome `jsoncallback` não existe.

Quando fazes:

```
echo $_GET["jsoncallback"];
```

Estás a tentar aceder a uma entrada da matriz que não existe.

Para melhor controlares isso deverás fazer uso da função [isset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) do PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET["jsoncallback"])) {
  echo $_GET["jsoncallback"];
}
else {
  echo "Não foi localizado: jsoncallback";
}
```

---

**Nota:** Deverás verificar se no endereço da página tens um parametro de URL com o nome `jsoncallback`.

[Variável Reservada GET - PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters.

Que traduzido:

> Um array associativo de variáveis ​​passadas para o script atual através dos parâmetros de URL.

Comment: O problema não está no código, como comentei, ele funciona perfeitamente em dois servidores, apenas neste que instalei agora via Xampp que ocorre este erro, é configuração do apache ou do php.

Comment: Acabei de testar em outro computador agora. O retorno ao executar o php não gera erro. Faz o retorno do Json perfeito. O que pode estar faltando no outro computador?

Comment: @user3771516 No teu `php.ini` verifica por acaso se tens a opção `cgi.force_redirect = 1`. Se sim, o problema poderá vir dai, deverás comentar essa linha e voltar a testar. (Já não me recordo se é preciso reiniciar, mas por via das duvidas, reinicia.)

Comment: @user3771516 De notar que o JSON pode estar a vir com problemas unicamente pelo facto de teres um `Notice` do PHP que é enviado junto com o JSON resultando numa falha ao ler o mesmo. Também podes indicar ao PHP para não apresentar `Notice` apesar que a melhor coisa a fazer é o que coloquei na resposta. Coloca `error_reporting(0);` no início do teu ficheiro PHP e deverá desligar os `notice`.

Comment: Agora estou em um computador que não gera o erro. No ini, a linha cgi.force_redirect = 1 estava comentada. Tirei o comentário da linha, e reiniciei o Apache, mas não mudou nada. Aqui continua tudo rodando. Se conseguir simular a falha aqui, descubro o problema no outro computador. Mais alguma idéia?

Comment: @user3771516 1. Desliga os `Notice` conforme te mencionei à pouco e testa. 2. Comenta a linha que referiste porque é suposto estar comentada. 3. Usa o inspector do navegador para ver o que te é devolvido, se for o `Notice` e a seguir o JSON é porque está tudo a funcionar como esperado mas o `Notice` está-te a quebrar o output, desligando deverá ficar ok (ps: convém claro estares a testar na máquina com o problema).

Comment: Fiz mais alguns testes, mas continua com a mensagem. Aparentemente o Json está sendo executado, mas abrindo direto o .php, retorna erros como o informado acima. O codigo utilizado está na postagem http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22497/passar-valores-para-arquivo-php-com-json